# How WEKA compute Sum of Squared-Error Value or SSE?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I am new with WEKA.

I would like to know how the WEKA get the SSE value of their Simple K-Means algorithm?

My friend and I implemented a java implemented K-Means algorithm, and with the same dataset, our java implemented algorithm get SSE value of only around 400 while WEKA get around 2000. How could this possible?

My friend also said that WEKA uses K-Means++. Could this be one of the reasons to make them have a different result?

Any idea will be much appreciated. Thanks
And please correct me if there's anything I say wrong. I would love to learn.

Comment: Are you using cross fold validation or just a train / test split?

Comment: @steve you don't do cross validation with unsupervised methods.

Comment: @ErichSchubert Thought they were using this as part of the classification framework :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you normalized your data?

Different normalization will cause both different results and different SSE values.

Also try exporting the result, and then using the same implementation to compute both SSE values.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that is the issue, we haven't been normalised our data, and do data cleansing and stuffs thanks for the response